# sockets server writes back to client

Tags: c, sockets

I have a question about sockets. I understand basically server-client relation should be noted below. But my question is, what if server needs to write back in that case how coding should be?does client need accept() etc?

server side

```
socket(...);
getaddrinfo(....);
bind(...);
listen(...);
accept(....);
read(....);
//what if server needs to write to client
```

client side

```
socket(...);
getaddrinfo(....);
connect(...);
write(....);
//what if client needs to read
```

Comment: After the first five calls (server side) or three calls (client side) in your question, the connection "forgets" which side is the server and behaves symmetrically. Either side can read or write.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Server<>Client comms is full duplex.

The server can write to the same server<>client socket used by the read() call and similarly, the client can read from the same socket used for the write() call.